# Looking for a lightweight MFC line graph library

Tags: mfc

I need to draw 2d line chart on a MFC view which will be implemented in real-time or close-real-time application. I would like it if it is very simple so that I can quickly draw the graph, with a thread if possible. Surprisingly, I can't find good one over google. I tried PGL but found it has lots of memory leaks and is slow. Can you recommend a graph library for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't many MFC component libraries left. Most of them went .NET and there were never many good freeware products for MFC.

One that is still sold ($100 developer, $500 distribution license) is

http://www.advsofteng.com/cdcpp.html

Comment: Thanks for recommending this library. It's amazingly fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3214/2D-Graph-ActiveX-Control

HTH

Comment: Sorry but I can't use ActiveX control chart in my app as its response is relatively slow.